# Synchronise back-end url routing with front-end url routing

Tags: angularjs, django, angular-ui-router

Maybe my title is not the best. Let me explain.

So, I've got this angular app that have some URLs bound to controllers.
And also a backend app(it's Django, but it doesn't matter much).

I want to send something to the front-end app with a action URL. So, it's like a link that, if clicked, would go to the corresponding URL specified by the backend.

I use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to handle URL routing on my angular app.

The problem is: I want those URL's to correspond on each side. So I want a way that I could send a identifier from my backend server and the frontend app will know what to do. I thought about using ui-router url naming system. Something like this:

```
n = Notification()
n.action_url = 'my_url_identifier_here'
send_to_front_end(n)
```

that works because the first parameter for changing the state of my view using ui-router is a string, which is the identifier of the state I wanna go to. But the second parameter is an object, that's the parameters for the next state. I think I could have two fields on my backend: `identifier` and `parameters`. `parameters` would be a json string that would be parsed as an object and we should be good to go. But that approach looks lame to me and I wanted something more elegant.

Can you guys help me out with this?

**EDIT:**

I also feel that the approach I currently aim wouldn't take too long to get reeeeally messy.

**EXAMPLE AS REQUESTED IN THE COMMENTS:**

I wanted to handle that without having to add a new if for each URL as suggested in the comments.

So, using the notification example above:

the front end would convert this `action_url` to something like `#/my/url/identifier/here`. That's a case with no parameters.
But, if action_url was `'other_url_id(param1, value1, param2, value2)'` the front end would convert this to url: `#/other/url/id/` and parameters `{param1: value1, param2: value2}`.
The system should behave the same way if `other_url_id` changed to `#/changed/this/url`

Comment: A bit unclear why u want this? I.e. user clicks some link and your backend decides where user goes depending on... what? What is their so special that frontend doesnt know? Why frontend itself cant decide this?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Actually, there's something the backend doesn't know: what identifier goes to what url. If I use #/my/path/to/url/ I might decide later that I want this to be #/my/path/ That way, the backend will get lost and send the wrong url to the frontend.

Comment: User click link->backend returns if (smth) state1, params321, if(smthelse) state2, params2 ->frontend goes to this state. Right? I wonder why this if can not be located on client side?

Comment: To be clear this is what you require -> you need a way to make sure urls names on both the frontend and backend to be the same, i.e. they should return the same url. Is that correct? E.g. you use url name 'something' on the backend, which gives you '/something', and you also want 'something' to mean the same thing in the front-end?

Comment: Can you edit the question with an **example** (an expanded version of your previous comment) of what you want to happen and what pitfalls you'd like to avoid. For example, user is at state `product.details`, and the servers sends `"edit"` command that causes the state to change to `product.details.edit` - or something like that.

Comment: @NewDev done. Also tried to say why solution would work in a short period.

Comment: @PatrickBassut, you are describing a system behavior, but what I asked for is an objective - an example of what you are trying to achieve. What are these URLs? What do they signify for the frontend and the backend? Why the backend even "reasons" in terms of front end URLs and vice-versa.

Comment: Well, I'll try to answer your question even though I think I don't fully understand what you mean. So, each notification has a "what's gonna happen" attribute. Depending on the notification I want the frontend to take a different action. If the backend notified a user to pick something up at the market, the next state is gonna be a market. Those are volatile, and can change easily(the urls paths), so I want a way to make this easily exchangeable without easily breaking things. That's why I'm trying to send to the frontend a state name, that way he figures out what to do.

Comment: Let me know if I answered your question, please.

Comment: @PatrickBassut, then I'm unclear why you are insisting on sending urls or state names. Create a conceptual model of "actions" (or whatever) and let the frontend deal with its own translation of action-to-state (or whatever else the frontend wants to do). The backend shouldn't even care about urls (e.g. `#/do/some/thing`, whether encoded like `do_some_thing` or not) or about frontend states. These things should be conceptually decoupled from each other.

Comment: Hmmm. I was thinking about using this approach but was afraid of ending up with lots of if's. But I can easily go around that with javascript.

Comment: @NewDev the problem is, sometimes there's parameters. I can't just say to the frontend that the action is x because it needs parameters to this action. Maybe do something like ```my-action-here-10``` where 10 is the parameter?

Comment: @PatrickBassut, I think you misunderstanding my point. However you communicate to the frontend, it should be completely decoupled from the concept of states or URLs. Return as complex an object as you need from the backend, e.g.  `{action: "foo", params: {a: "123", b: "456"}}`... Then let the frontend handle this request however it wants. The backend should not care about frontend states, nor should it care about ***how*** the frontend will go about achieving this request

Comment: And, technically, this would work passing a json string from the backend and then parsing it on the frontend, right? Yeah, sounds good

Comment: @PatrickBassut, the serialization of an object (via JSON or otherwise) is not really important to my point. Yes, JSON is preferable because it's native to Javascript, but parsing is for the most part already done for you. For example, `$http.get("some/url/")` will de-serialize the returned JSON into an object.

Comment: Looks neat. I'll use that, thanks so much!